# "Abstract class does not take parameters": why?

Tags: scala, inheritance, methods, abstract-class

I'm studying Scala and I'm trying to translate the code of some design pattern from Java to Scala, but I lose some detail.

For example, now I write a simple *State* but I receive three occurrences of the same error in compile time:

This is the code

```
abstract class Statelike {
    def writeName(STATE_CONTEXT : StateContext ,  NAME : String): Unit
 }

class StateA extends Statelike {
   override def writeName( STATE_CONTEXT : StateContext ,   NAME : String) : Unit = {
        println(NAME.toLowerCase());
        STATE_CONTEXT.myState(new StateB)  **//same error**
    }
}//end StateA 


class StateB  extends Statelike {
     var count = 0;
     override def writeName( state_contest: StateContext , name: String) : Unit = {
     println(name.toUpperCase());
     count+1;
     var conto2 = count;
     if (conto2 > 1) {
        state_contest.myState(new StateA)     **//same error**
     }
    }
}//StateB  

class StateContext {

    var state : Statelike = null

    def StateContext() {
        myState(new StateA)   **//same error**
    }

    def myState_=(s1 : Statelike ) = {state = s1}

    def myState : Statelike = state

    def writeName ( NAME : String): Unit =  {
        myState.writeName(this, NAME);
    }
}//end StateContext 

object TestClientState {
    def main( args : Array[String]) { 
        var SC = new StateContext();

        SC.writeName("Monday");
        SC.writeName("Tuesday");
        SC.writeName("Wednesday");
        SC.writeName("Thursday");
        SC.writeName("Friday");
        SC.writeName("Saturday");
        SC.writeName("Sunday");
    }
}
```

The error occurences are:

```
State.scala:12: error: Statelike does not take parameters
        STATE_CONTEXT.myState(new StateB)
                             ^
State.scala:26: error: Statelike does not take parameters
            state_contest.myState(new StateA)
                                 ^
State.scala:37: error: Statelike does not take parameters
        myState(new StateA)
               ^
three errors found
```

reading the doc, it likes an uncorrect use of traits, but I'm not using the traits!

The *StateA* and *StateB* are the implementing class of class *Statelike*, what is abstract.
No more, no less.

Where's my code error? A too much "Java-style" inheritance? Waht can be a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess what you r trying to fdo is make getters and setters explicit, try instead of `state_contest.myState(new StateA)` `state_contest.myState = new StateA`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler is puzzled what you are trying to do here:

```
myState(new StateA)
```

Well... I'm puzzled too. `myState` is a method without parameters.

```
def myState : Statelike = state
```

So you could rewrite your code like this:

```
val ms: Statelike = myState
ms(new StateA)
```

Since `ms` is not a method the last line (`ms(new StateA)`) is the shorten version of `ms.apply(new StateA)`. But there is no method `apply` in class `Statelike`.

Maybe you want to call `myState.writeName(new StateA)` instead of `myState.(new StateA)`, but there is not enough parameters for method `writeName`.

**Setter**

As @AlexIv mentioned: If you are trying to call setter, you should note that it's name is `myState_=`, not `myState`.

```
myState_=(new StateA)
```

With syntax sugar:

```
myState = new StateA
```

Comment: He is trying to make getters and setters explicit, like when scalac desugars vals. Instead of `myState(new StateA)` he should write `myState = new StateA`, beacuse of `def myState_=(s1 : Statelike ) = {state = s1}`, and in this case make `var state` private

Comment: 2 my error: 1)  _def StateContext()_ : the signature os the class is the constructor, differently by Java I must'nt declare an explicit constructor. 2) bad call of myState_, the correct code is class.myState _ = (/*new value*/). Ihneritance is'nt a problem

Comment: @alepuzio: 1) Yes, `def StateContext()` is a common method, not a constructor. You could set `state`: `var state : Statelike = new StateA`. And even if you don't want set `state` you could use `_` instead of `null`: `var state : Statelike = _`. `_` works with all types, not only `AnyRef`.